# Local terraform repository, remote ec2 with assumed role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

My current setup is:

- My local machine (actually one for each developper)
- A git repository containing my terraform configuration
- An EC2 instance which assumes an IAM role which grants it permissions to apply my terraform configuration.
- A clone of the git repo inside this EC2 instance
- Me connecting via SSH from my local machine to the EC2 instance and running terraform

I would like to change the situation to:

- No git clone on the EC2 instance
- No specific rights on my local machine
- Keep using the EC2 instance with the assigned role to deploy terraform

Is it possible to run terraform from my local machine and have terraform be using the remote EC2 instance's role without having to copy the files there?
Terraform would need to connect to the remote EC2 instance using SSH and run the needed steps or could perhaps use an ssh tunnel?
If necessary, I could setup a proxy on the remote EC2 instance. Or maybe that's what terraform provisioners are for?

Thank you in advance for your answers and sorry for my lack of terraform knowledge.
Please don't hesitate to let me know if what I'm trying to achieve is stupid. (Maybe personal rights on each local machine is better and more auditable?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sshfs in the EC2 machine allowing you to mount files from your local machine in one of the EC2 directories. In this way, you can execute terraform commands on the remote machine with files stored in your local machine.

Of course, you'll have to install sshfs in the EC2 machine and create a user in your local machine:

1. The terraform user in the EC2 machine must have permission to establish SSH sessions with that user
2. The configuration files have to be accessible for that user

The EC2 machine would mount one of its EC2 directories on your local repository for files.

If the local machine is behind a NAT, you could use reverse ssh tunnels to allow the access from the EC2 machine to the local machine. The EC2 machine would use one of its ports to access the client. That could also solve the problem to allow connections from different clients. All those clients would be accessible through the same port and same user

Comment: Using sshfs is technically copying the files even if it's kind of transparent. I'd like to know if there is another way